# do I need to close addOnCompleteListener

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

do I need to close addOnCompleteListener

I only need to read once from the Cloud Firestore.
After that, do I need to close the addOnCompleteListener by using like .remove()?

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to remove listeners added to Task objects like the one returned by Firestore's `get()` method.  The listener will trigger once and only one, and that's the end of it.