# When should I remove OnCompleteListener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309256/do-i-need-to-remove-listeners-added-to-a-task-with-addoncompletelistener) where it says  there is no need to remove any listener when using `get()` function, does this apply for  `set()`, `update()` and `delete()`?

How can I distinguish when the listener is needed to be removed or not? I'm very confused and I'm struggling with this listener stuff for days. Thanks.

Comment: quoting from the answer you linked "There is no need to remove listeners added to Task objects" seems pretty clear

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks for your comment but does the same rule apply in case of `set()`, `update()` and `delete()`? If yes, how can I know when to remove `OnCompleteListener` and when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to remove a listener if you're actually using a true *listener* - ie, listening to live updates on a record. So if you're just using `get` or `set` or `update` or `delete`, those are one-time events with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` that don't need a true *listener* despite the name (and don't need any listener removal). You would just likely want a completion handler (eg, `addOnSuccessListener`) so you can do something after the query is done.

If you're using something like `onDataChange`, you're polling/listening to the data for changes and you'll want to remove that listener when you switch screens or navigate away from that component.

The naming confuses things a little in Java/Kotlin for this reason - think of a *listener* and the need to remove it if you're *watching* or *monitoring* the data in a polling manner. If you're just doing one-time transactions, no need to remove anything.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I understood the first part regarding `get` or `set` or `update` or `delete` but now I'm confused regarding the last part. What is `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and what is `onDataChange`?

Comment: When you query your database, you set up a reference (ref) to the object you want to query. Then, you either use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to get that object (once) or use `onDataChange` to get the object AND keep watching listening to that object - as new changes happen to the watched object, you get the updated object.

Comment: I understand now what you are saying. Please see that I use Cloud Firestore not realtime database. There is no `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` here :| Does your answer still apply to Cloud Firestore?

Comment: Ah - yes. It still applies, but with a different naming convention. In Firestore, your one-time queries (no listener unsubscribe needed) will use `.get().addOnSuccessListener()` and your watchers/polling would use `addSnapshotListener` in which case you'd want to `remove()` the listener before the component/page is removed.